UIAutomator: can one combine multiple By-selectors?
In a UI Test-Case I want to check whether a listView element contains two children "foo" and "bar" (say), like so:
        UiObject2 listView =
            device.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.ListView")
                .hasDescendant(By.text("foo"),0)
//              .hasDescendant(By.text("bar"),0)
            );

But this does not work. If I comment the second line (as shown) then findObject(...) returns me a valid listView-object. If I uncomment the second line, too, then I always get null as result, even though the list does contain both elements.
I searched for some .and()-method as is sometimes found in other frameworks or some similar helper that would allow to combine multiple selectors for the same object, but didn't spot anything in that direction.
How can one phrase a BySelector that checks for two different,  independent descendants that are either
a.) both present (i.e. an "and"-condition) or
b.) alternatively present (i.e. an "or"-condition)?
